# Javascript push multiple objects into an empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to achieve a data structure in javascript that looks like this:

```
settings: {
   { "key": "Language", "value": "en" },
   { "key": "Language", "value": "en" }
}
```

The amount of keys is variable and needs to be iterated over. I thought I could do it with an array but the [0] numbers are getting in the way.

This is what i have now:

```
convertSettingsToApiSaveFormat(values) {
        const keys = Object.keys(values);
        const items = Object.values(values);

        const valuesToSend = keys.map((key, i) => {
            return { key, value: items[i] };
        });
        return { settings: [valuesToSend] };
    }
}
```

Which returns:
[image]

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Expected output is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: What is the type of the parameter `values`?

Comment: You can't expect like this, In every javascript object `{}`, the `key name` is required to hold a value

Comment: Just remove the brackets: `return {settings: valuesToSend}` - it's already an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is an invalid data structure

```
settings: {
   { "key": "Language", "value": "en" },
   { "key": "Language", "value": "en" }
}
```

JavaScript object is bascally key value pair  you can see the bellow two objects dont have and key.

Either it can be like this

```
 settings: {
   "someKey":  { "key": "Language", "value": "en" },
   "someKey2": { "key": "Language", "value": "en" }
}
```

or a simple JS array

```
settings: [
   { "key": "Language", "value": "en" },
   { "key": "Language", "value": "en" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're placing `valuesToSend` inside an array - remove it, and you'll get your desired output<sup>*</sup>:

```
return { settings: valuesToSend };
```

<sup>*</sup> The result you currently want is invalid - this, however, is valid:

```
settings: [
  { "key": "Language", "value": "en" },
  { "key": "Language", "value": "en" }
}
```